# How can I go to next Activity in Android Studio when Firebase auth is successful?

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase-authentication

Next activity is not loading instead app crashes when Firebase Auth is successful.

I have written the intent object for jumping to next activity inside `if(task.isSuccessful)` function but app crashes instead.

```
//LoginActivity.java
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
      startActivity(new Intent(
      LoginActivity.this, UserActivity.class));
      finish();

    } else {

      toastMessage("An Error Occurred while Logging-In");
    }
```

When I use Toast to show if task is successful, the toast shows the auth to be successful, but when I write code for going to next activity, App crashes.

Comment: in this code there is no error there is possible of the error in your next activity

Comment: please include stacktraces